# Using slots when running a rasa server

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am working on a django appication. The application has a form with which a user can chat with a bot. This is just a test application for learning and the bot cannot do much.

For the chatbot, I trained a rasa model with a few intents and entities. Once the model was trained, I ran the model as a server with the following command

```
rasa run -m models --enable-api --log-file out.log
```

When the user types a message in the form and submits the form, a request is sent to the rasa server and the intent and entities of the message is received as a response.

Now my question is, is there any way for me to use [slots](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/) to store some of the entities, so as not ask the user for info already provided. And if this is not possible, how do I use rasa core features like stories and slots with django? When I tried researching on this, I could only find on how to use the bot with slack.

I am a beginner with very little experience with rasa and chatbots

Please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Domain.yml:
Initialize the same name for entity and slot.

```
entities:
client_name

slots:
 client_name:
 type: unfeaturized
```

For further reference checkout the link :-
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/